# WordPress Ajax Get Request?

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I have a page that includes a php file I have written like so

HTML

```
<div id="playlists_div_holder">
    <?php include(dirname(__FILE__) . '/includes/get_playlists.php'); ?>
</div>
```

I have created a button that will refresh the playlists , incase the user has uploaded (added/removed) anything, and I am trying to do so with an ajax request to get the file and include it back into that div, but I am receiving a 500 error.

I am doing this in WordPress so that may be an issue.

The Button

```
 <span class="button-primary refresh-playlists" onclick="ReloadPlaylists()">Refresh Playlists</span>
```

Ajax Request

```
function ReloadPlaylists() {
  jQuery.get('<?php echo plugins_url();?>/Player/includes/get_playlists.php', function(data) {
      jQuery('#playlists_div_holder').html(data);
      alert('Load was performed.');
    });
}
```

Including it works but an ajax get throws a 500 error

Comment: it seems like that something's wrong on the server side. You need to review your server logs.

Comment: i'm getting call to undefined function get_option on line 8 , which is odd because it works when i include it the first time. Could it be because its calling the same file on the other and it has some sort of variable conflict?

Comment: That's because you didn't include `../../../wp-blog-header.php` and once you do that you will get an Error 404 because that URL is not registered in Wordpress URL ReWrite. You can override that by using `header()` function

Comment: Please can you show us the content of get_playlists.php? Where is placed the include statement( metabox, options page)?

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty hard to guess the problem but some simple workarounds that you can use all the time:-

**CAUTION! Please take backup of your WordPress before doing anything.**

1st workaround:-

1. Download fresh WordPress copy
2. Delete every folder, **except the wp-content folder.**
3. Upload all the files and folders again, **except the wp-content folder.**

2nd workaround:-

Rename

```
wp-content/themes
```

to

```
wp-content/themes-backup
```

Create a new folder:-

```
wp-content/themes
```

start copying each theme from *themes-backup* to *themes* one by one and see if the error is gone.

Now what you have done with the themes folder, do exactly with the plugins folder.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment,

> i'm getting call to undefined function get_option on line 8 , which is odd because it works when i include it the first time. Could it be because its calling the same file on the other and it has some sort of variable conflict?

This is because when the plugin in running as an include, all the wp-includes are laoded before your plugin code is execute. However when you make an AJAX call directly to that file, the wp-includes are no loaded hence your `get_option()` isn't working.

You can fix that by adding `include_once("../../../wp-blog-header.php");` on top of your get_playlists.php file. That might break your plugin (not sure) so in that case its safe to use it inside a condition like this

```
if(stristr($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], get_playlists.php))
    include_once("../../../wp-blog-header.php");
```

However once you do that you will get an Error 404 when you make an AJAX request because that URL is not registered in Wordpress URL Rewrite. You can override that by using `header()` function.

```
if(stristr($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], get_playlists.php)) {
    include_once("../../../wp-blog-header.php");
    header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
}
```